# Rotation matrix for direction vector

Tags: java, math, vector

I've been playing with some algorithms on the internet for a while and I can't seem to get them to work, so I'm tossing the question out here;

I am attempting to render a velocity vector line from a point. Drawing the line isn't difficult: just insert a line with length `velocity.length` into the graph. This puts the line centered at the point in the y-axis direction. We need to get this now in the proper rotation and translation.

The translational vector is not difficult to calculate: it is half the velocity vector. The rotational matrix, however, is being exceedingly elusive to me. Given a directional vector `<x, y, z>`, what's the matrix I need?

**Edit 1:** Look; if you don't understand the question, you probably won't be able to give me an answer.

Here is what I currently have:

```
                    Vector3f translation = new Vector3f();
                    translation.scale(1f/2f, body.velocity);

                    Vector3f vec_z = (Vector3f) body.velocity.clone();
                    vec_z.normalize();

                    Vector3f vec_y; // reference vector, will correct later
                    if (vec_z.x == 0 && vec_z.z == 0) {
                        vec_y = new Vector3f(-vec_z.y, 0f, 0f); // could be optimized
                    } else {
                        vec_y = new Vector3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
                    }
                    Vector3f vec_x = new Vector3f();
                    vec_x.cross(vec_y, vec_z);
                    vec_z.normalize();

                    vec_y.cross(vec_x, vec_z);
                    vec_y.normalize();
                    vec_y.negate();

                    Matrix3f rotation = new Matrix3f(
                        vec_z.z, vec_z.x, vec_z.y,
                        vec_x.z, vec_x.x, vec_x.y,
                        vec_y.z, vec_y.x, vec_y.y
                    );

                    arrowTransform3D.set(rotation, translation, 1f);
```

based off of [this article](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article665.asp). And yes, I've tried the standard rotation matrix (vec_x.x, vec_y.x, etc) and it didn't work. I've been rotating the columns and rows to see if there's any effect.

**Edit 2:**

Apologies about the rude wording of my comments.

So it looks like there were a combination of two errors; one of which House MD pointed out (really bad naming of variables: `vec_z` was actually `vec_y`, and so on), and the other was that I needed to invert the matrix before passing it off to the rendering engine (transposing was close!). So the modified code is:

```
                    Vector3f vec_y = (Vector3f) body.velocity.clone();
                    vec_y.normalize();

                    Vector3f vec_x; // reference vector, will correct later
                    if (vec_y.x == 0 && vec_y.z == 0) {
                        vec_x = new Vector3f(-vec_y.y, 0f, 0f); // could be optimized
                    } else {
                        vec_x = new Vector3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
                    }

                    Vector3f vec_z = new Vector3f();
                    vec_z.cross(vec_x, vec_y);
                    vec_z.normalize();

                    vec_x.cross(vec_z, vec_y);
                    vec_x.normalize();
                    vec_x.negate();

                    Matrix3f rotation = new Matrix3f(
                        vec_x.x, vec_x.y, vec_x.z,
                        vec_y.x, vec_y.y, vec_y.z,
                        vec_z.x, vec_z.y, vec_z.z
                    );
                    rotation.invert();
```

Comment: Your question is near-impossible to understand, especially the part about "half the velocity vector".

Comment: Why do you call vec_z.normalize twice, and what is the <x, y, z> here?

Comment: That was a typo in the original code. It didn't actually make a difference to the final solution, but it would have made the y scaling kinda funky. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dupe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193918/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-align-the-z-axis-with-a-vector)

> The question there involves getting a rotation to a certain axis, whereas I'm concerned with getting a rotation matrix.

Gee, I wonder if you could turn [convert one to the other](http://www.google.com/search?q=angle+axis+rotation+to+matrix)?

BTW, your current solution of picking an arbitrary y axis and then reorthogonalising should work fine; it looks bugged though, or at least badly written. '`z_vec`' is not a good variable-name for the y-axis. What's with the 'z,x,y' ordering, anyway?

If it still doesn't work, try making random changes until it does - transpose the matrix, negate vectors until you have an even number of sign errors, that kind of thing.

Also your tone of voice comes across as sort-of rude, given that you're asking strangers to spend their time helping you.

Comment: The question there involves getting a rotation to a certain axis, whereas I'm concerned with getting a rotation matrix.

Comment: See my comments on the above answer. Yes, I could do that, but I'd like to get the above implementation working.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've been working for several hours on this, so I'm quite frustrated right now.

Comment: NP. I trust that randomly flipping vectors did the trick? Gotta love graphics programming...

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html) should do you

Comment: This does not work, as I do not have angles; only the desired direction vector.

Comment: You can work out the angles using basic trig...

SOH CAH TOA

If you don't know your basic trig you shouldn't be moneying around with vectors...

Comment: I know I can work the angles out, but that's extremely inefficient. It should be possible to figure out the matrix using only cross products.

Comment: If you can't spell 'monkeying' then you shouldn't be monkeying around with English.